# Sqlserver getting to much time fetch the details

Tags: sql-server

I have table like below,

```
Id(Pk)     User_Id      C1       C2     C3     C4
1          111          2        a      b      c
2          111          5        d      e      f
3          111          7        a      f      ty
4          222          2        a      b      c
5          222          5        d      e      f
6          222          7        a      f      ty
```

This table almost having 10L records. And each user_id having almost 10k Records. If I am fetching details by User_id, it is getting almost 5 mins to get the details. Where i have to tune this?

Im using below query

```
Select * from User where user_id ='111'
```

And total number of columns in this table is around 130 columns.

Comment: What indexes do you have on that table?

Comment: ID is primary key. but im searching by User_id, which does not have any index.

Comment: And do you get 10k records from your query and do you really need all that 10k records?

Comment: Of course add an index to `user_id` - it is the filter condition!

Comment: you definitely required index on the user_id column

Comment: What datatypes do you use, int, char, varchar, nvarchar, and which length?

Comment: Yes i need all 10k records.

Comment: Did you already try the Database Engine Tuning Advisor? It comes with SQL Server.

Comment: If you don't have any indexes, and you have 10L's (What is an "L"? I assume a larger number than 10,000) then the only way SQL Server will be able to find all the relevant rows is by a table scan. @juergend is right, you need to add an index. It sounds like you don't have any indexes on the table, which for one with millions (unsure) of rows is a must.

Comment: user_id is int type

Comment: And this table almost having 130 columns. 10L means 1000000

Comment: And the other types? nvarchar for instance uses two bytes, whereas varchar only uses one.

Comment: most of all other columns are nvarchar.

Comment: But do they need to be nvarchar? This is only required in case of UNICODE.

Comment: Yes. most of columns are String only. so it needs to be nvarchar/varchar only.

Comment: I would really advice to use the Database Engine Tuning Advisor. This might result in some nice suggestions improving performance based on workload.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a right index defined on (`User_id`) & just select the column which you actually want so, i would do with backed `SSMS`:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT  User_Id, C1, C2, . . .  
FROM User 
WHERE user_id = 111;
```

If, relative index is not present with `user_id` then you have to pay with poor performance.

Note : If `user_id` has numeric type, then you don't need to use `''`.

Comment: No. After putting 'Set Nocount on' also not working. and this table having almost 130 columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you PK on the `Id` column is a clustered index, change it to non-clustered and create a clustered index on the `User_Id` column.

This will most likely make SQL Server use a partial table scan, and as all requested records will be saved "close to eachother", this might reduce the number of page reads required to retrieve the values (which can be "grabbed" from the disk without further criteria checks).

Comment: This might have some impact when inserting new records though.

Comment: Yes, it might, of course. The index can be prepared with a fill factor according to the expected daily growth of the table, and a nightly job should re-orgenize the index.